# SQLite: Select record based on select result values on same table

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table Fields. Example:-

```
id  remote  unique_id
1   23  30007
1   24  30008
1   1   30009
2   4   30007
2   5   30008
2   1   30009
3   6   30007
3   7   30008
3   2   30009
```

here i want to get sum of unique_id field=30008 remote value where unique_id field=30009 remote value = 1;

basically, what i want is: 
(query 1)

```
select SUM(remote) from Fields where unquie_id = '30008';
```

and one added filter where:(query 2)

```
select remote from Fields where unquie_id = '30009';
```

i want to select the _id record of query 2 where remote=1 for my query 1.

So the above output would be: `24+5=29.`

Here i am selecting _id as 1,2. _id =3 would be rejected as it remote for unique_id = 30009 is 2.

This might be simple for you guys but i am new with sqlite. Hence please help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually run it, but something like this should do what you need:

```
select SUM(remote) from Fields as F where F.unique_id = '30008' and F.id in (select remote from Fields as G where G.unique_id = '30009');
```

---

So I tested it:

```
create table Fields(id integer, remote integer, unique_id integer);
insert into Fields(id, remote, unique_id) values (1, 23, 3007), (1, 24, 30008), (1   ,1   ,30009), (2,   4,   30007), (2 ,  5 ,  30008), (2  , 1  , 30009), (3  , 6,   30007), (3  , 7,   30008
), (3 ,  2 ,  30009);
/*select * from Fields;*/

select SUM(remote) from Fields as F where F.unique_id = '30008' and F.id in (select remote from Fields as G where G.unique_id = '30009');
```

And the ouput was: **29** as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you want to sum the `remote` column where the `unique_id` is `30008`, but only for those `id` groups having `remote=1` and `unique_id=30009`.

```
SELECT SUM(f1.remote)
FROM Fields f1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM Fields
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN unique_id = '30009' AND remote = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) f2
    ON f1.id = f2.id
WHERE unique_id = '30008';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `exists`

```
select sum(remote) total 
from Fields f 
where exists (
    select 1 from Fields 
    where remote = f.id and unique_id = 30009
) and f.unique_id = 30008
```